# Print CSV rows only if particular column is not empty

Tags: shell, csv

I am trying to access the csv file which is big one and if the particular column is empty i am trying to put the row into other other csv for further process. I have written the piece of code to process the same but the problem is that one column is having huge data with spacing hence my code is taking that column as a separate line.

```
IFS=$'\n'
for line in `cat file.csv`; do
    echo "Processing for $line"
    res=`echo $line | cut -d ',' -f2`
    if [ '$res' != '0' ];then
        echo $line >> results.xlsx
    fi
done
```

Comment: You should read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: And xlsx is **not** a text format; appending csv text to a file of that type will just corrupt it

Comment: Finally, shellcheck is your friend. Always run scripts through it on a regular basis when writing and debugging them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use awk for it. First some data:

```
$ cat assumed_data
1,2
3,
4,5
```

the awk:

```
$ awk -F, '$2==""' assumed_data
```

the output:

```
3,
```

and some explanation:

- `awk` using awk for the job
- `-F,` set input field delimiter (`FS`) to a comma
- `'$2==""'` condition: if the second field is empty execute action and the default action is to output current record
- `assumed_data` file to process