# Python: Write list to CSV only if a specific column is not empty

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm getting data from an API and appending it to a list `data_list`. There are 10,000+ rows to this.

I am writing each row of this API output into a CSV with the following:

```
for row in data_list:
    with open(filename, 'a') as c:
        writer = csv.writer(c)
        writer.writerow(row)
    c.close()
```

Sometimes there are rows where columns 5 and onwards are empty (i.e., item 5 in the list onwards is empty), and instead has `''`

Instead of having to manually delete them in Excel, I was wondering how I could just avoid writing rows with empty columns 5 instead.

**Extra info:**

Normal row:

`[123, 'Title', 'Name', 456, 'Surname', 789, 101112, 131415, 161718, 0]`

Row with empty columns:

`[123, 'Title', 'Name', 456, 'Surname', '']`

I tried looking at this [Print CSV rows only if particular column is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837927/print-csv-rows-only-if-particular-column-is-not-empty) but it did not work the way I intended it to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for row in data_list:
    with open(filename, 'a') as c:
        writer = csv.writer(c)
        if row[5] != '':
            writer.writerow(row)
    c.close()
```

Comment: For some reason this leaves column 5 empty and shifts everything else down 1 column

Comment: @corybantic can you describe the structure of data_list?

Comment: Is it like data_list= [[123, 'Title', 'Name', 456, 'Surname', 789, 101112, 131415, 161718, 0],
[123, 'Title', 'Name', 456, 'Surname', ''],[123, 'Title', 'Name', 456, 'Surname', 789, 101112, 131415, 161718, 0]]?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df = df.dropna() # drops rows with an empty value in any column, otherwise use df.dropna(subset=[5])
df.to_csv("filename.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Any way to do this without pandas?